# How to get a canvas to resize correctly without clipping.. Specific Script

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, clipping

I am using this great script for clipping jpegs.

```
var polyClip = new function () {
    function s(b, c) {
        q[b] = new Image;
        var e = q[b];
        $(c).attr("data-polyclip-index", b);
        $(e).bind("load", function () {
            d.drawShape(b, c)
        });
        e.src = c.src
    }
    var d = this,
        r, k = [],
        q = [];
    d.isOldIE = window.G_vmlCanvasManager;
    d.init = function () {
        r = $("img[data-polyclip]");
        r.each(s)
    };
    d.drawShape = function (b, c) {
        var e = $(c),
            a = document.createElement("canvas");
        a.width = c.offsetWidth;
        a.height = c.offsetHeight;
        a.id = "polyClip" + b;
        var l = jQuery.trim(e.attr("data-polyclip")).split(","),
            j = c.src;
        k[a.id] = [];
        e.replaceWith(a);
        d.isOldIE && G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(a);
        for (var f = a.getContext("2d"), e = 0; e < l.length; e += 2) {
            var h = parseInt(jQuery.trim(l[e])),
                i = parseInt(jQuery.trim(l[e + 1]));
            k[a.id].push({
                x: h,
                y: i
            });
            e == 0 ? f.moveTo(h, i) : f.lineTo(h, i)
        }
        if (d.isOldIE) f.fillStyle = "", f.fill(), a = $("fill", a).get(0), a.color = "", a.src = c.src, a.type = "tile", a.alignShape = false;
        else {
            var g = new Image;
            g.onload = function () {
                var a = f.createPattern(g, "repeat");
                f.fillStyle = a;
                f.fill();
                a: {
                    for (var b = parseInt(jQuery.trim(l[0])), c = parseInt(jQuery.trim(l[1])), e = -1; e <= 1; e++) for (var d = 0; d <= 1; d++) if (a = f.getImageData(b + e, c + d, 1, 1).data[3], a != 0) {
                        a = true;
                        break a
                    }
                    a = false
                }
                a || g.src.indexOf("?chromeError") < 0 && (g.src += "?chromeError")
            };
            g.src = j
        }
    };
    d.findObject = function (b) {
        var c = b.currentTarget;
        if ($(c).hasClass("cropParent")) return $(c);
        for (var e in k) if (k.hasOwnProperty(e) && (c = $("#" + e), d.isInPolygon(c, b.pageX, b.pageY, true))) return c
    };
    d.isInPolygon = function (b, c, e, a) {
        var d = b.get(0),
            d = k[d.id],
            j = d.length,
            f, h, i, g, o, m, p = false,
            n = {
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            };
        a && (n = b.offset());
        if (j < 3) return false;
        f = d[j - 1].x + n.left;
        h = d[j - 1].y + n.top;
        for (m = 0; m < j; m++) b = d[m].x + n.left, a = d[m].y + n.top, b > f ? (i = f, o = b, g = h, h = a) : (i = b, o = f, g = a), b < c == c <= f && (e - g) * (o - i) < (h - g) * (c - i) && (p = !p), f = b, h = a;
        return p
    }
};
document.write('<style type="text/css">img[data-polyclip], img.polyClip { visibility: hidden; }</style>');
polyClip.isOldIE ? $(window).bind("load", polyClip.init) : $(document).ready(polyClip.init);
```

It works great for what I am doing.  I am using fluid widths within the div so all widths are percentage based.  Only problem is, unless it's a full browser screen it clips the canvas.  If it is full browser, the image renders fine.  When I open it full browser and resize that works out fine as well.  The problem I am having is when I open it in a resized browser or on an iphone it clips the image and keeps it at roughly 960px,

So in Full Browser It looks like this:

XX-----Full Image----xx

On resize from full browser still looks good:

xx-Resized Image--xx

On load from a smaller screen screen

xx-----Full Ima

Any help would be appreciated.  It is also good to remember that the whole design is intended to be fluid and it is working so far with the exception of this small snag.

Comment: Please show us a non-minified, readable version of your script.

Comment: What code gets run when the browser resizes?

Comment: This is the code it renders after running:

Comment: <div class="clipParent">
<canvas id="polyClip0" width="960" height="228"></canvas>
<canvas id="polyClip1" width="960" height="298"></canvas>

Comment: Why do you write CSS styles through JavaScript?

Comment: I didnt write this script it was from here:  https://github.com/zoltan-dulac/polyClip.  It clips jpegs that are not rectangular.

Comment: @Joe Can you give us your complete code? You said you use fluid widths, but that library doesn't use them.

Comment: @oriol There is so much code I wouldn't even know where to begin.  I guess the easiest thing to do would be to show you the url I am referring to:  salestemplate.com It is a customized wordpress twenty eleven theme

Comment: @Joe It doesn't solve your problem, but I think you need `#polyClip0{width: 100%;}`

Comment: Yeh. I was messing with that to see if it would do anything.  With the width @ 100% it resizes down, but it always renders and clips at full width on smaller width browsers

Comment: Figured this out.  You can close it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it well, you have the image

[image: img1]
<sub>(source: [salestemplate.com](http://www.salestemplate.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/toptrim.jpg))</sub>

(The white part is white).

and you want to convert to

[image]

(The white part is transparent).

Then, once you have the transparent one, you can get the image base64 encoded:

http://jsfiddle.net/fAUbp/show/

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA78AAADkCAYAAABQQZMzAAAgAElEQVR4nOy955Mk252el/bkSZ9ZWd679r572kxPj+3x3pvr5nqDC1wAC3OxIBZYYBfcpSjFUhRD1JIRCumLDMVgKPQPPvqQVTXVM5XV9/YsCCnID0+8VWlPZeXJ...
```

(rest omitted for brevity)

Then, paste that to your browser's URL bar, download it to your computer and upload the image to your server.

Finally, use the new transprent .png image instead of the first .jpg.

This way, instead of generating the transparent one each time an user visits your site, you generate it only once.